# how to call function from python script from different directory in shell

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7

i am trying to run function from python from different directory with

`python -c 'import /advg/users/ibrahims/test-coverage-files/coverage.py;  coverage.InitliazeResultHtml'`

i get the following output :

```
  File "<string>", line 1
import $location;  $location.InitliazeResultHtml
       ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can you please help me how to run InitliazeResultHtml from /advg/users/ibrahims/test-coverage-files/coverage.py script in shell ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error means what you type was not correct, python don't understand what you type. I think you should simply type python to enter interactive mode, and then do what you want.

```
import sys
sys.append(your path to this file)
```

You can google python module to see how to import.

I know why you got that problem, you should not use ' ', you should use " ".Try this to see whether it helps.

Comment: i am trying to call python function in shell from other directory , and i am getting this error , what i am asking is how to call it properly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/279237/6490497 you can check this question. I have edit my answer and you try it.